# How to access Apple Id "Sign In" dialog from UI Test

Tags: swift, automation, ios-ui-automation, xcuitest

I have one  UI tests and want to  test that  I press "close" button. In simulator there is an alert displayed asking to sign in with your  apple id.
Please see attached Image in URL

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQmmw.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This alert is part of the Springboard so to handle it you can use either:

```
let springboard = XCUIApplication(bundleIdentifier: "com.apple.springboard")
springboard.alerts["Sign in with your Apple ID").buttons["Close"].tap()
```

or

```
let springboard = XCUIApplication(bundleIdentifier: "com.apple.springboard")
springboard.alerts.element(boundBy: 0).buttons["Close"].tap()
```

Comment: Thanks mate it worked , however sometimes failing also , as 50 percent chances to work

Comment: I suggest you add a wait condition for the button to exist and be hittable before attempting to tap it and you should be able to stabilize it :)

Comment: yes i used that only mate :)